# Logging in Module - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

In MAIN_SETUP.py program I am importing otherMod2

MAIN_SETUP.py

```
import logging
import otherMod2


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    """
    The main entry point of the application
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger("exampleApp")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # create the logging file handler
    fh = logging.FileHandler("new_snake.log")

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)

    # add handler to logger object
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    logger.info("Program started")
    result = otherMod2.add(7, 8)
    logger.info("Done!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

otherMod2.py

```
import logging

module_logger = logging.getLogger("exampleApp.otherMod2")


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
def add(x, y):
    """"""
    logger = logging.getLogger("exampleApp.otherMod2.add")
    logger.info("added %s and %s to get %s" % (x, y, x + y))
    return x + y
```

If I run the program (MAIN_SETUP.py), new_snake.log file is created, following data is written in the file

```
2018-12-03 16:21:29,772 - exampleApp - INFO - Program started
2018-12-03 16:21:29,772 - exampleApp.otherMod2.add - INFO - added 7 and 8 to get 15
2018-12-03 16:21:29,772 - exampleApp - INFO - Done!
```

Question 1 :

In otherMod2.py , we do have below logger, it's just defined and not used . Can we delete it? Will it have any impact if we delete it.

```
module_logger = logging.getLogger("exampleApp.otherMod2")
```

Question 2:

There is no handler defined for below logger in otherMod2.py but still its writing in new_snake.log file, how this is possible

```
logger = logging.getLogger("exampleApp.otherMod2.add")
logger.info("added %s and %s to get %s" % (x, y, x + y))
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer both questions:

**Question 1**

You can delete the module-level logger `exampleApp.otherMod2`, however, you might want to keep it so that other code within the module can use it.

Creating a module-level logger is the [recommended approach](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects) - typically by calling `logger.getLogger(__name__)`. That sets up a logger using the same hierarchy as the module's package structure.

**Question 2**

Python loggers are constructed within a hierarchy which is determined by the dots in the logger's name. By default, events logged lower down the hierarchy are also passed to loggers higher up the heirarchy.

So although your `exampleApp.otherMod2.add` logger has no handler, the event is passed up to the top level `exampleApp` logger which outputs it to the log file.

This behavior is controlled by the [`propagate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) attribute. You can set this to `False` so that higher level loggers won't receive the events.

```
logger = logging.getLogger("exampleApp.otherMod2.add")
logger.propagate = False
logger.info("added %s and %s to get %s" % (x, y, x + y))
```

In that case you would need to attach a handler to `exampleApp.otherMod2.add` if you wanted it to output anything.